# How to show: $\exists$ L such that $X\neq L\oplus L^{\perp}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, inner-products

$X$ : inner product space

$L$ : closed subspace of $X$

How to show: $\exists$ L such that $X\neq L\oplus L^\perp$

let $X= (\text{the set of  all finite sequences}, \|\cdot\|_2 )$

$L=\lbrace x\in X: \sum^\infty_{n=1}x_n/n=0\rbrace$

Then: How to show that $L^\perp =\lbrace 0\rbrace$?

Comment: This isn't true in general - if $X$ is a hilbert space, then $X = L \oplus L^\bot$ for every closed subspace $L$.

Comment: @fgp: the $X$ in the question is not a Hilbert space. That's the whole point.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Ah, I should have read more carefully, I was under the impression the OP wanted a construction that works for every inner product space, which due to the reason I mentioned is impossible. I overlooked that he want the construction for a *specific* inner product space, the space of all finite sequences with the $\|\cdot\|_2$-norm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let be $y\in L^\perp$. Suppose that $y\neq 0$. Then, there is some $j\in\Bbb N$ such that $y_j\neq 0$. Since $y$ is a finite sequence, there is also $k\in \Bbb N$ such that $y_k=0$.

Now define $x$ this way: $x_j=1$, $x_k=-\frac kj$, and the rest of terms $0$.

$x$ is in $L$ since
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x_n}n=\frac 1j-\frac k{jk}=0$$

The inner product $\langle x,y\rangle$ is
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n\bar y_n$$
but since $y_k=0$ and $x_n$ is $0$ for each $n$ other than $j$ and $k$, the sum has only one nonzero term, and it is at index $n=j$: $x_j\bar y_j=\bar y_j$, so that $\langle x,y\rangle=\bar{y}_j\neq 0$, a contradiction with that $y\in L^\perp$.

Comment: I hope I have put things a bit clearer

Comment: Thank you very much @ajotatxe