# Is it possible that we can find an infinite dimensional inner product space $V$, and a linear subspace $U\subset V$ such that $V\neq U\oplus U^\perp$?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, inner-products

Is it possible that we can find an infinite dimensional inner product space $V$, and a linear subspace $U\subset V$ such that $V\neq U\oplus U^\perp$? And if so, how can we prove such a thing? (Sorry if this is a stupid question for some of you, However I am still new to these topics)

Comment: Would [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/761750/how-to-show-exists-l-such-that-x-neq-l-oplus-l-perp?rq=1) work?

Comment: Oh yes it definitely helps thanks!